# Does cross-validation for model selection using MSPE make sense for mixed models?

Tags: prediction, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

Does cross-validation for model selection using mean square prediction error make sense for mixed effect models such as produced by lme4?  If so, under what conditions / caveats?

Also, are there any written materials where the writers of lme4 describe the calculation of predictions?